# I want to display image from internet from main activity to another activity?

Tags: android

I want to display image from internet from main activity to another activity. But it is not working. What I have done:

// Main Activity

```
gameListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

            // Find the current game that was clicked on
            Games currentGame = mAdapter.getItem(position);


            // Convert the String URL into a URI object (to pass into the Intent constructor)
            Uri gameUri = Uri.parse(currentGame.getUrl());

            // Create a new intent to view the game URI
             Intent i = new Intent(GamesActivity.this,PreviewActivity.class);
             i.putExtra("value",gameUri);
             startActivity(i);


        }
    });
```

// Second Activity

```
public class PreviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView img;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_preview);

    img = findViewById(R.id.imagePreview);

    Uri i = getIntent().getData();

    Picasso.with(this).load(i).into(img);
        }
}
```

Comment: I guess your question is "why doesn't this work" ? You're saving the URL as extra data then trying to read it back from the main value. Try saving it with `setData`, or reading it back with `getExtra`. You also ought to cope with getIntent returning null in the second activity, e.g. if it was started some other way.

Comment: Thank u very much, u solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Intent intent=getIntent();
    String i=intent.getStringExtra("value");
Picasso.with(this).load(i).into(img);
```

And url in string form.

Comment: I did that before uploading the question

Comment: first check url  if it is ok then try this it may happen bcz  of version conflict Picasso.get().load(i)
                .fit().placeholder(PUT SOME PLACEHOLDER")
                .into(img);

Comment: thank's a lot, I used setData() instead of putExtra() and the problem were solved.